# "Uninitialized value" false positive

Tags: perl, embedded

I think that PERL (5.8.8 on CentOS kernel 2.6.18-308.8.1.el5) is giving me a false positive 'uninitialized variable' warning. All of my searching turns up legitimate uninitialized value problems. Perhaps mine is too, and if that's the case then an explanation of what's going on (and how to correctly do what I'm trying to do) would be awesome. I've also looked at many references for hex() and correct function argument idioms, and I think I'm doing all of that correctly.

My script reads 2 text files: one contains 32bit hardware address and the other contains 32bit data read back from that address. The values in each file are always 8 hex digits long and both files are 100% matched (line 1 in the Address file corresponds to line 1 in Data file). When the data value is non-zero everything is fine, but when the data value is 0 I get the warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at ../VMetro_Parser.pl line 248.
Use of uninitialized value in hex at ../VMetro_Parser.pl line 250.
```

Relevant code:

```
sub ppReg_TX_Mode_Reg {
    my( $data ) = @_; # first arg should be the Data field
    my $ret = "\t";
    if( $data eq "00000000" ) { print "TX_Mode_Reg got 0 input\n"; } #LINE 248
    #croak( "data not defined!" ) unless defined $data;
    my( $hex ) = hex($data); #LINE 250

    $ret .= sprintf( "Clear INTs: %02X   ",         (($hex >> 25) & 0x7F) );
```

Input that produces expected behavior:

```
Address: 90000004
Data: 00000004
```

Output of PERL script:

```
90000004 00000004 ->  Wr TX00 Mode_Reg
    Clear INTs: 00
```

Input that produces the unexpected 'uninitialized value' warning:

```
Address: 90000004
Data: 00000000
```

Output of PERL script:

```
90000004 00000000 ->  Wr TX00 Mode_Reg
TX_Mode_Reg got 0 input
    Clear INTs: 00
```

Clearly, it is recognizing an argument passed in as the string "00000000" and yet it also thinks it is undef (the croak line fires if I uncomment it). What gives?

One interesting thing is that there are other instances of the data being 0 but no warnings are thrown. This other 0 data is processed by a different function, and occurs after the line that throws the warning, but the processing is identical (except for the obvious debug actions in the code above, that were only added because of the warning).

E.G.

```
sub ppReg_RX_Master_Mode_Reg {
    my( $data ) = @_; # first arg should be the Data field
    my $ret = "\t";
    my( $hex ) = hex($data);
```

Does not throw any warnings.

Comment: There's no warnings in what you claim is the output?!?!

Comment: The name of the language is "Perl". It's not an acronym.

Comment: `use Devel::Peek qw( Dump ); Dump($data);` (before the compare) might be instructive.

Comment: You should check your input with `Data::Dumper`. It is a very good way to debug scripts, and also a core module. `print Dumper $data` will let you know exactly what's in your variable. Also, there is not enough information in your question to do anything but guess, so I suggest you set up a self-contained example, if possible.

Comment: @TLP, Data::Dumper doesn't let you know "exactly what's in your variable". That's what I suggested Devel::Peek. If this is a bug in Perl, the extra detail would matter.

Comment: We can't tell from what you posted what argument `ppReg_TX_Mode_Reg` received. Can you reproduce this with a smaller script? Please post a complete example.

Comment: Sorry about separating the warnings from the output. I had redirected the output to a file so I could copy/paste it here, and I didn't recombine it correctly.

I figured out my problem and will post an Answer below, but I wanted to mention that Data::Dumper really helped show what was going on. I had trouble importing Devel::Peek, so I never got to try that. If I can figure out how to vote up a comment, I'll do that for y'all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, the problem was with my code and not Perl :)
I am using a Dispatch Table to call my processing functions. **A typo in the Dispatch Table definition caused the function to be called when Perl was processing the declaration of the table.**

Offending Code:

```
# 'Dispatch table' is a hash for functions
my %regPPFn = (
        TX_Version_Reg  =>  \&ppReg_TX_Version_Reg,
        TX_Mode_Reg =>  \&ppReg_TX_Mode_Reg,
        TX_Run_Reg  =>  \&ppReg_TX_Run_Reg,
        ...
        # Note: GCs are mostly TXs, so mostly call the TX fn()s
        GC_Version_Reg  =>  \&ppReg_TX_Version_Reg,
        GC_Mode_Reg =>  &ppReg_TX_Mode_Reg,
        GC_DMA =>   \&ppReg_GC_DMA,
        GC__Reg =>  \&ppReg_GC__Reg,
        "" => sub { print "Dispatch table NULL lookup\n" }
        ); # Array of pointers to register Pretty Print functions
```

You can see that the function reference for *GC_Mode_Reg* is missing the backslash before the ampersand.

```
GC_Mode_Reg =>  &ppReg_TX_Mode_Reg,
```

should be

```
GC_Mode_Reg =>  \&ppReg_TX_Mode_Reg,
```

Using Data::Dumper was a great first step to getting me on track and showed me that my function was being called one time before it "could ever possibly be called". Using $| = 1 also helped me believe the output text ordering; I had thought that the warning messages coming out ahead of my print statements was due to buffering.

Since the solution was a good deal away from the initial hypothesis / question title, let me know if & how you think I should edit this question. I hesitate to change it much since someone else with the same problem will probably be looking in the wrong place the same as I was.

Answer (score 1):

This is very unlikely to be a problem with Perl.

Remember that warnings are sent to STDERR whereas your output is going to STDOUT. The two aren't necessarily in sync, so you can't tie up the warning with the output for the same record.

It may help to use `print` and `die` instead of `croak` so that the warnings are displayed in the correct sequence.

I suggest you change your subroutine to

```
sub ppReg_TX_Mode_Reg {
  my ($data) = @_;
  do { warn 'Undefined $data parameter'; return; } unless defined $data;

  . . .
}
```

so that the code isn't executed for invalid data.

Your problem is likely to be in the code that extracts the data from the file records. Are you handling blank lines correctly? Please show this part of the code if you want help with it.

Comment: Adding `$| = 1;` (to disable buffering on STDOUT) could help with such issues too.